# django: how to get a substring?

Tags: python, django, satchmo

I was modifying satchmo(a python online store project), but I found that I can't use [0, 5] to get the substring in the model. And I found the type is  class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeUnicode' in django string processing.

Does class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeUnicode' support [0, 5] to get the substring as in python?

Comment: you have a comma where you should have a colon for slicing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slice it.
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html

```
>>> 'foobar'[0:5]
[Out] 'fooba'
```

---

Update: sure, why not?

```
>>> django.utils.safestring.SafeUnicode('foobar')[0:5]
[Out] 'fooba'
```